# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForFreeDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, android-testing, android-proguard, android-instrumentation

I have created an app with free and paid flavors and multidex is also enabled. 
I have written and InstrumentationTest to test some codes.

When I am running the test the following error appears. Is there any idea what might be the cause and solution to this problem.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForFreeDebugAndroidTest'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```